# MSVS2012 c++ nmake how do run nmake on a makefile in a subdirectory?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, makefile, nmake

I have a project with a top-level makefile and three sub-folders each with a makefile in them.

In normal makefiles (gnu make) I can do this:

```
# Just for me so I can read my own makefile -->  TARGET: DEPEND
_TARGET = $@
_DEPEND = $<

# Sub projects to build in dependency order
SUB_PROJECTS = folder2 folder1 folder3

.PHONY: $(SUB_PROJECTS)

all: $(SUB_PROJECTS)
@echo makeing all

$(SUB_PROJECTS):
@echo "*******************************"
@echo "*   MAKING: $(_TARGET)"
@echo "*******************************"
$(MAKE) -C $(_TARGET)
@echo
```

Where here I am basically calling `make -C folder1` to run make on the makefile in sub folder "folder1".

So I am trying to translate my gnu makefile into nmake. For the most part I have not had too much trouble (the .phony thing is different to here).

But I can't seem to find the syntax to call nmake on the sub folder:

`nmake folder1` does not work. I looked at all the flags for nmake an non of them looked obvious. The documentation on nmake is not easy to navigate (i.e. to find what you want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe nmake has anything like (gnu)make's `-C` option, you'll need to do something like

```
$(SUB_PROJECTS):
    cd $@
    $(MAKE) /$(MAKEFLAGS)
    cd $(MAKEDIR)
```

Comment: That's a fair point and pretty straight forward : )  .. but I just stumbled across another method which might be better because of the "echo line runs in its own shell" thing - i'll put it down as an answer as well see what you think

Comment: @code_fodder Yeah your solution seems pretty much equivalent although there's no risk for multiple shells with this one as it doesn't rely on a continuous environment as `pushd` does. By the way you should consider using `$(MAKE) /$(MAKEFLAGS)` in place of `nmake` as it propagates options and makes sure the same nmake binary is executed.

Comment: Good points both... I do use $(MAKE) normally but not in this example...  but the makeflags is a good idea : )

Answer (score 1):

I just found this link: [UsingNmake](http://wiki.c2.com/?UsingNmake) which suggests:

**Traversing Directories  "makefile"**

```
 DIRS = \ 
         dir1 \ 
         dir2 \ 
         dir3

 all: $(DIRS)

 $(DIRS):
         pushd $@ & nmake & popd
```

It explains why this is better to do it in one line...