# Setting NMake Makefile directory

Tags: windows, makefile, nmake

GNU Make has the option to change to a directory where the make file is before running make:

`make -C <Makefile dir here>`

Is it possible to do the same thing with NMake? I can't seem to find the flag for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MSVS2012 c++ nmake how do run nmake on a makefile in a subdirectory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49635064/msvs2012-c-nmake-how-do-run-nmake-on-a-makefile-in-a-subdirectory)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a flag for that. But this is essentially just changing directory before executing make and getting back afterwards, so you should be just fine with:

```
pushd <dir> && nmake & popd
```

Note the first `&&` causes `nmake` to run only when `pushd` succeeded, while `&` allows to execute `popd` regardless of `nmake` exit code.